# PHP PDO SQLITE - connection

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter, pdo, connection

Is this a correct way of setting up a PDO connection to a SQlite database in php?

```
new PDO(";dbname=sqlite:c:/path/database.sqlite", "", "");
```

Because this throws me an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Because whenever I leave the **;dbname=** part out, it doesn't give me this error anymore.

So what is the correct way?

**PS**: I have set up the drivers correctly in php.ini, see this link for a screenshot of phpinfo(): http://puu.sh/2xtEF.jpg

Comment: Run phpinfo() and check your drivers.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but I already have set up all my drivers correctly. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like if you leave the ;dbname= part, it's just the hostname (DSN).
So it should be either

```
"sqlite:c:/path/database.sqlite"
```

or

```
"sqlite:c:/path/database.sqlite;dbname=whateverthenameis"
```